# To read Excel can we use Spring batch?

Tags: database, excel, spring-batch

I want to know if it is possible to use **Spring Batch**, in order to read from 
an file Excel and save it in Database.

**remark :** the content of file Excel chang every 2 hours.

And if it is not possible with Spring Batch, what other solution can i use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go take a look on [spring-batch-extensions for Excel](https://github.com/mdeinum/spring-batch-extensions/tree/master/spring-batch-excel). You will find some examples of ExcelItemReader and ExcelItemWriter.

Here is the introduction of the spring-batch-extensions project for Excel :

> Spring Batch extension which contains ItemReader implementations for Excel. Support for both JExcel and Apache POI is available. Simple xls documents can be read with both implementations, however for reading the newer xlsx format Apache POI is required.

You just need to [import sources into your IDE](https://github.com/mdeinum/spring-batch-extensions#import-sources-into-your-ide) and use them.

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-excel</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Above dependency can be added for as Excel Item Reader(PoiItemReader).